# Onenote 2013 vs 2010 issues with scrolling touch

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010, microsoft-onenote-2013

In 2010 onenote I could use fingers for scrolling and moving around the page and then pen only for writing or drawing. Now in 2013 as soon as I draw, the finger input also becomes drawing. In 2010 onenote you could have a default action for finger input and for the pen. And say If I wanted to use the pen as an eraser I had to choose said eraser with the pen. If I click eraser with pen in 2013 every input becomes eraser. Really super irritating.

I think I'm installing 2010 again, because the interactive experience in 2013 is just sad. I hope someone has a fix. I'm out of licences for 2010 (just got a new laptop, the helix) and will have to buy it again if this can't be fixed.

Edit: A little summary. Can OneNote 2013 differentiate between digitizer and touch input?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem with OneNote 2010. I couldn't scroll using my mouse wheel nor using the touchpad on the laptop.

The problem was solved in a few steps:

1. Uncheck checkbox in *Options* -> *Advanced* -> *Automatically switch between inking, selecting, typing and panning*.
2. Restart OneNote.
3. Check the same checkbox again (*Options* -> *Advanced* -> *Automatically switch between inking, selecting, typing and panning*).
4. Restart OneNote.

Answer (score 0):

It really just seems to be a buggy driver or something. I rebooted. And now I can pan around with my finger and draw with the pen.